# Add script to object in script Unty

Tags: unity-game-engine

I try to make something in Unity:
I create object - sphere by script and I want to add for this sphere other script, but dynamically in code. How can I do it? :)

```
GameObject sphere = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
sphere.tag = "SuperBall";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **AddComponent** method from GameObject, just like that:

```
YourScript sc = sphere.AddComponent<YourScript>();
```

Source: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.AddComponent.html

Comment: I didn't know I can use AddComponent for this operation! Thank you so much :D